# Is it possible to deploy multiple Spring Boot applications to a server?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, jar, war

We can create restful API in spring boot jar file?

1)can we split multiple jar file in Apache server?

2) if we split multiple jar file how will identify which jar contain correct rest APIs

How spring boot jar file will work in server?

Comment: If you create an executable jar with Spring Boot it will have all its dependencies and an embedded Tomcat server encapsulated in it. You don’t need to deploy it to a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## For Development Environment

You can configure ports via `application.properties` or via `system properties`.
Or with option to jvm `--server.port=8081`
So, there is no problem to run a few APIs on single machine with different ports.
You don't need Apache Server. Spring Boot has it's own embedded for you. So, you can easily use it.

Let's say you have two APIs.

- `localhost:8081` (Checkout Service)
- `localhost:8082` (Payment Service)

Hostname and port - it's your identification for each service.

When you trying to search something in Google.
You browser - it's a client.
And Google's servers - it's a server.

The same here. Checkout Service trying to delegate some job to Payment Service. So, Checkout Service - it's a client. And this client should know the address of Payment Service.

## For Production Environment

You should think twice, how you will monitor performance, manage scalability and so on.